# How to insert empty line in array environment with custom delimiter `@{...}`?

Tags: arrays, line, grammar

I am using the `array` environment with `\begin{array}{l@{::=}ll}` to typeset a formal grammar:

[image: Rendered version of the LaTeX code below showing the ::= delimiter in the supposedly empty line]

**How can I insert an empty line without my delimiter `::=` appearing there?**

Minimal working example:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{l@{\quad::=\quad}l@{\quad}l}
        T   & \varepsilon \mid \mathrm{leaf} \mid \mathrm{bin}(T, T) & \text{trees}\\
        \\
        F   & \varepsilon \mid F, T                                  & \text{forests}
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use an empty `\multicolumn`, as its column specifications override the specifications of the tabular/ array it is inserted in.:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{l@{\quad::=\quad}l@{\quad}l}
        T & \varepsilon \mid \mathrm{leaf} \mid \mathrm{bin}(T, T) & \text{trees}\\
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & &\textit{Fiddle dee dee }\\\\
        F & \varepsilon \mid F, T & \text{forests}
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ComFreek  Bernard has essentially done that as he used `\multicolumn{1}` so only removed the `@` from the first column, try `\multicolumn{1}{c}{aaa}&bbb&ccc\\ ` this will still give you the `\quad` from the second `@`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I see now that `\multicolumn{1}{###}{...}` can be used to "override" the column layout & delimiter of the current column by `###` with column contents `###`! I think *that* information is worth adding. So `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&&\text{dummy header}` would produce the expected row for me.

Comment: @ComFreek: I've added some words about what \multicolumn does and some nonsense text in the third column.

Answer (score 5):

Some suggestions and observations:

- Instead of inserting a not-so-empty line in the `array` via a `\\` directive, just increase the amount of vertical skip after the first `\\` directive by, say, `3ex`.
- Setting an explicit intercolumn whitespace amount of `\quad` is redundant in most document classes, i.e., in all those document classes which set the value of `\tabcolsep` to `6pt` and the value of `\quad` to `12pt`. Unless specified otherwise, intercolumn whitespace amounts to `2\tabcolsep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{ l @{\quad::=\quad} l l }
        T   & \varepsilon\mid\mathrm{leaf}\mid\mathrm{bin}(T, T) & \text{trees}\\[3ex] 
        F   & \varepsilon\mid F, T                               & \text{forests}
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```